# .acsauto script to save to relative filepath

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, avaya

I have an .acsauto script from Avaya CMS system that is saving data into a text file on a specified location:

```
b = cvsSrv.Reports.CreateReport(Info,Rep)
           If b Then        
           stuff
           b = Rep.ExportData("C:\Long\File\Path\report.txt", 59, 0, True, True, True)
```

Is there a way to make this address relative on the .ascauto script location so that the report is created e.g. next to it? The script language should be either VB or VBScript - nobody knowledgeable about the system is able to tell me - but I have not been even able to replace the direct reference by a string (the report seems to run, merely it is not saved to the desired location)

```
strFilePath = "C:\Long\File\Path\report.txt"
b = Rep.ExportData(strFilePath, 59, 0, True, True, True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with this code change:

```
dim fso, strPath
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
B = ...
     strPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName("report.txt")
     b = Rep.ExportData(strPath, 59, 0, True, True, True)
```